# OWL Carousel 2 adding class to item

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Im working on a slider that contains two synced owl-sliders.
sync1 is main slider and sync2 is thumbnails slider. When I click on one of elements of second slider sync1 goes to proper slide.
Now goes my issue:

When user clicks on any of thumbnail a green border should appear on clicked elemment and should stay there until another element is clicked.

I've tried to use jquery .addClass and .css but nothing happens.

I think that I should add div with "position: absolute" that holds up to clicked element, but I don't know how to do it. Please help! :)

Here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var sync1 = $("#sync1");
var sync2 = $("#sync2");
var index2=0;
var flag=true;


var slides = sync1.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    nav: false,
    mousedrag: false,
    touchdrag: false,
    pulldrag: false

});

$(document).on('click', '.prevbutton, .nextbutton',function() {
    sync1.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');

});

sync1.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    var index1=event.item.index;
    var index11 = index1-2;
    //console.log("index1", index1)
    //console.log("index11", index11);
    sync2.trigger("to.owl.carousel", [index11, 100, true]);
});


$('.nextbutton').click(function() {
    //console.log(sync1);
    sync1.trigger('next.owl.carousel');

});

$('.prevbutton').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    //console.log(sync1);
    sync1.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [500]);


});


/* thumbnails*/

var thumbnails= sync2.owlCarousel({
    items: 6,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    mousedrag: false,
    touchdrag: false,
    pulldrag: false,
    addClassActive: true
});
/*buttons*/
$('.nextbutton2').click(function() {
    sync2.trigger('next.owl.carousel');

});


$('.prevbutton2').click(function() {
    // With optional speed parameter
    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
    sync2.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [500]);


});


sync2.trigger("to.owl.carousel", [index2, 100, true]);
sync2.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    index2=event.item.index;
    //console.log("index2", index2);
    index22=index2-1;
    // sync1.trigger("to.owl.carousel", [index22, 100, true]);
});
// console.log("index2", index2);

sync2.on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(e.target).parents('.owl-item').index()-6, 300, true]);
    // console.log("clicked index", $(e.target).parents('.owl-item').index())

});



$('#stopcontainer').on('mouseover', function(){

    if ($('#stopcontainer:hover').length != 0) {
        flag=true;
        console.log("flaga", flag);
    }
    if (flag==true) {
        sync1.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
        console.log("mousein");
    }

}).on('mouseleave',  function() {
        setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                if ($('#stopcontainer:hover').length == 0) {
                    flag=false;
                    console.log("flaga", flag);
                }
                if(flag==false){
                    console.log('mouse leave');
                    sync1.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
                }

            }, 5000)}
);

});
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions when you post questions.  This question doesn't have anything to do with the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]).

Comment: Note that http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ was made to fix the problems in Owl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
sync2.on('click', '.owl-item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.some-class').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.some-class:first').addClass('active');
});
```

There is empty div with "some-class" inside carousel item, and when you click on this element class "active" is added